# Sqoop: How to map input column names to different column names in Hive?

Tags: hive, sqoop

Is there any way to do mapping between input column names and output Hive column names in Sqoop command line or Scoop API?

For example:

```
Input SQL table:
(Name STRING, Phone INT)

--> need to map into -->

Output Hive table:
(ClientName STRING, PhoneNumber INT)
```

I have to do this because Hive does not support Unicode in table schema and can not parse Cyrillic column names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a free-form query import (--query option) and say something like

```
--query 'select Name as ClientName, Phone as PhoneNumber' ...
```

Comment: Glad that helped. BTW some good news is coming in Hive 13, you will be able to use Cyrillic in column names with backticks (you will need to set an option.) See the comments section of HIVE-6013 for more detail.