# Valid MySQL query breaks when used as boundary-query

Tags: sqoop

**Note**: This is NOT a duplicate of [Sqoop - Syntaxt error - Boundary Query - “error in your SQL syntax”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53694497/3679900)

---

To limit the fetching data from only last 8 days, I'm using this following `boundary-query` with `Sqoop`

```
SELECT min(`created_at`),
       max(`created_at`)
FROM `billing_db`.`billing_ledger`
WHERE `created_at` >= timestamp(date(convert_tz(now(), IF(@@global.time_zone = 'SYSTEM', @@system_time_zone, @@global.time_zone),'Asia/Kolkata')) + interval -2 DAY)"
```

*I've broken query into multiple lines here for readability, actually i pass it to Sqoop in single line only*

Explaination of different parts of boundary-query are

1. `IF(@@global.time_zone = 'SYSTEM', @@system_time_zone, @@global.time_zone)`

   - determines server timezone
   - works for both MySQL & TiDB
2. `convert_tz(now(), <server-timezone>,'Asia/Kolkata')`

   - converts time from server-timezone in IST
3. `timestamp(date(<ist-timestamp> + interval -{num_days} DAY)`

   - returns the IST timestamp at 00:00 hours for date whih is {num_days} before today (current-time -> tz-specific)

---

While the query works fine on MySQL

```
mysql> SELECT min(`created_at`),
    ->        max(`created_at`)
    -> FROM `billing_db`.`billing_ledger`
    -> WHERE `created_at` >= timestamp(date(convert_tz(now(), IF(@@global.time_zone = 'SYSTEM', @@system_time_zone, @@global.time_zone),'Asia/Kolkata')) + interval -2 DAY);
+---------------------+---------------------+
| min(`created_at`)   | max(`created_at`)   |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2020-05-08 00:00:00 | 2020-05-10 20:12:32 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

It breaks with following stacktrace on Sqoop

```
INFO db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: BoundingValsQuery: SELECT min(), max() FROM . WHERE  >= timestamp(date(convert_tz(now(), IF(@@global.time_zone = 'SYSTEM', @@system_time_zone, @@global.time_zone),'Asia/Kolkata')) + interval -2 DAY)
[2020-05-10 12:45:34,968] {ssh_utils.py:130} WARNING - 20/05/10 18:15:34 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hadoop/.staging/job_1589114450995_0001
[2020-05-10 12:45:34,971] {ssh_utils.py:130} WARNING - 20/05/10 18:15:34 DEBUG util.ClassLoaderStack: Restoring classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6ab7a896
[2020-05-10 12:45:34,973] {ssh_utils.py:130} WARNING - 20/05/10 18:15:34 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: java.io.IOException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=313686) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your TiDB version for the right syntax to use line 1 column 12 near "), max() FROM . WHERE  >= timestamp(date(convert_tz(now(), IF(@@global.time_zone = 'SYSTEM', @@system_time_zone, @@global.time_zone),'Asia/Kolkata')) + interval -2 DAY)" 
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat.getSplits(DataDrivenDBInputFormat.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:303)
```

---

For the record

- using `WHERE $CONDITIONS` is required in `--query` (free-form query-import) but for `--boundary-query` it is NOT mandatory. Without it, Sqoop merely generates this warning

  `WARN db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: Could not find $CONDITIONS token in query: SELECT min(), max() FROM . WHERE  >= timestamp(date(convert_tz(now(), IF(@@global.time_zone = 'SYSTEM', @@system_time_zone, @@global.time_zone),'Asia/Kolkata')) + interval -2 DAY); splits may not partition data.`
- I've been using similar complex `boundary-query`s elsewhere in my pipeline but in this particular case it is breaking

---

What have I tried

- I tried adding *aliases* in `SELECT` clause of query like this

  `` SELECT min(`created_at`) AS min_created_at,... ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Backticks ``` `` ``` were the culprit*

Removing backticks from boundary-query resolved the error

- Some [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217677/sqoop-import-with-split-by-using-sql-function#comment89439071_51217677) in discussions point out that backticks can cause wierd things with `sqoop`
- But the [docs](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.7/SqoopUserGuide.html) bear no mention of it and some [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011886/sqoop-how-to-map-input-column-names-to-different-column-names-in-hive#comment33470892_22046042) even encourage using it